# Xcode UI Testing - can't find element that was just recorded

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode-ui-testing, ui-testing, uitest

I'm trying out Xcode UI testing. I've just recorded a simple test and replayed it and it's failing on the first step. The code is:

```
XCUIApplication *app = [[XCUIApplication alloc] init];
XCUIElementQuery *scrollViewsQuery = app.scrollViews;
[[scrollViewsQuery.otherElements containingType:XCUIElementTypeStaticText identifier:@"First Page"].element tap];
```

The line that's failing is the last one, and the error message is 'UI Testing Failure - No matches found for ScrollView'

Why is this failing? How can I interact with this element in this view?

Answer (score 0):

Try referencing the static text directly, instead of through the `otherElements` accessor.

`[scrollViewsQuery.staticTexts[@"First Page"] tap];`

Comment: I get the same error. It appears to be an error locating the scrollView rather than the static text within it?

Comment: Try accessing it on the app directly, then. `[app.staticTexts[@"First Page"] tap];`

Comment: Now I get UI Testing Failure - No matches found for StaticText. Same page. I even added a 5 second sleep before this just in case it hadn't loaded completely somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Is your application a menu bar app by chance? I've found that XCUITest has bugs when dealing with finding elements belonging to menu bar apps specifically.

Try making sure that in your "MYAPP-Info.plist" file, the entry "Application is agent (UIElement)" is set to "NO".